# js.erb file not getting triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, filterrific

I have three files:
Controller:

```
   def index
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      DimDictionary,
      params[:filterrific],
      select_options: {},
      persistence_id: 'shared_key',
      default_filter_params: {},
      available_filters: [ :dictionary_word_filter ]
    ) || return

    @dictionaries = @filterrific.find.limit(30)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Index.html.haml

```
= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f|
  .ui.form
    .fields
      .field
        Filter Word
        = f.text_field :dictionary_word_filter
  = render_filterrific_spinner
= render(partial: '/test/list', locals: { dictionaries: @dictionaries })
```

Index.js.erb

```
<% alert("hi"); %>
<% console.log('working Mannnnn') %>
<%  js = escape_javascript(render(partial: '/test/list', locals: { dictionaries: @dictionaries })) %>
$("#filterrific_results").html("<%= js %>");
```

The `Index.js.erb` is not getting triggered. Every time the page loads, its should run the `Index.js.erb` and show the alert and the console.log and the show the html right? Or the js.erb will only trigger on ajax request?

I am here using `filterrific gem` for filtration purpose but the index.js.erb file never gets triggered.

Even i have includes the js format in my controller. How should it be ? am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Every time the page loads, its should run the Index.js.erb and show
>   the alert and the console.log and the show the html right?

No, `format.js` means, that your controller returns JS in response, when client wants to JS.

You should use `remote:true` for example, if you want to JS in responnse. There is no possibility to render both, because controller action can only repond to one HTTP request at a time.

More about responses in Rails:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html

And about javascript in Rails:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: So if you read http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/example_application.html this gems documentation. They are triggering a ajax call to your controller and then the erb automatically updates the list but the problem is that everytime i do some action the gem form never triggered a call to my backendd

Comment: So, your problem concerns configuration of gem probably. Any logs with error from console?

Comment: There are no error's, like none.
I have previously used this gem for other project but i am facing problems with this now. I have configured everything correctly and it still dosent seems to work. Maybe you can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416093/filterrific-not-filtering-data

Comment: You can look at filterrific demo source code: https://github.com/jhund/filterrific_demo and compare your code. Check wheater you attach filterrific/filterrific-jquery to your application.js